# What questions would you ask a V-P of a Semiconductor Company?

Tags: physics, projects, electrical-engineering

I am working on a project for college with a classmate. Our subject is semiconductors. In the essay we have to write, we must discuss theory, practical uses, and economical implications. Our professor highly values the testimony of experts. So, we aimed for the sky, we contacted an important company and asked if any expert on the subject was available to answer some of our questions.

We were lucky, the company granted us 1 hour to ask any questions. My partner and I have about a week to prepare for the interview. Currently, we are reading all we can about semiconductors to have pertinent questions to ask during the interview. But we cannot become experts on the subject in one week.

So, I came here because you guys are more knowledgeable than I am. I wanted to gather ideas of questions I could ask during the interview.

Also, if any of you is an expert on semiconductors and would like to answer some questions or provide explanations, it would be greatly appreciated. However, please note, that I cannot take theoretical information from this subreddit unless you can prove that you are an expert (e.g. degrees in physics or electrical engineering).